# hdfs space is increasing drastically while updating documents in Solr

Tags: hadoop, solr, hdfs, solrcloud

​We are using Solr with HDFS for our indexing needs. While updating the existing documents(read existing doc and update) in our performance run, we observed that the HDFS storage space was growing exponentially. We are using the standard setting mentioned here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr+on+HDFS. Any clues on what could be root cause for our issue? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just thinking out loud: do you need to delete the existing document before updating it? i.e., read existing, build new doc, delete existing doc, then update. Asking this because you mentioned storage grew exponentially.

Comment: Solr does that automatically. No need to any manual deletion. And we got this problem only when Solr integrated with HDFS; on another filesystems it worked fine.

Comment: Is cleanup enabled?

Answer (score 0):

We have been testing different configuration values to solve this issue. So far it seems that by enabling solr.hdfs.blockcache.direct.memory.allocation=true in the solrconfig.xml file the issue is solved.